# How do I print the contents of my list into a text file?

Tags: c#, list, io

I have restaurant data and I am trying to analyze who visited a particular Restaurant X.  The data has this structure:

```
public class RestaurantXPatrons
{
    public String PatronName { get; set;}
    public List <strings> DateofVisits = new List <strings>();
}
```

I created a List of RestaurantXPatrons called lstX, and I want to output lstX to a tab-delimited text file (for viewing in Excel at a later time).  So here's my output code:

```
var output = lstX.Select ( x => x.PatronName + "\t" + x.DateofVisits );
string filepath = @"C:\data.txt";
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filepath, output);
```

When I view the results in Excel or Notepad, I see "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
" where there should be the contents of the DateofVisits list for each Patron of Restaurant X.  My question is, how do I get the contents of the list into my output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either do something like `x.DateOfVisits.FirstOrDefault()` (to get the first instance) or flatten the list to string like: `String.Join("; ", x.DateOfVisits)`.

Alternatively if you want to do something like:

```
Paul    01/01/2013
Paul    01/02/2013
Sally   01/01/2013
```

You could do

```
from x in listX
group x by new { x.PatronName, x.DateOfVisit } into g
select new String(g.Key.PatronName + "\t" + g.Key.DateOfVisit)
```

...don't have anything I can test with so this is all done "blind" as it were - hopefully will get you on right track.

Comment: @Steve Well you never know it could be `x.DateOfVisits = @"System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]"; :P

Comment: It is a `List<DateTime>`.

Comment: I am perfectly fine with flattening my list and it sounds like a solution to my problem.  Can you elaborate more on how to flatten a list into a string?  I can easily convert my dates into strings without problems to accommodate your solution.  I have altered my original code to be a list of Strings instead of a list of DateTimes.

Comment: Well to get your `List<DateTime>` to be `IEnumerable<string>` just do `listOfDateTimes.Select(a => a.ToString())`

Comment: @phan: You don't need to change the type of the list, the problem and the solution keeps the same.

Comment: I'd definitely keep them as a list of datetimes though (and just do the above to convert to strings) - don't want to loose that tasty type information

Answer (score -1):

you need to iterate through the collection (output variable) and then write them into a StringBuilder perhaps or write them directly to disk by using WriteLine on the StreamWriter object.

when you hover over the var variable, you will see it is a type of a collection being returned by the Select method (LINQ extension method). you need to iterate through it and write it line by line.

Comment: Basically, there is an overload for `WriteAllLines` that takes an `IEnumerable<string>`..

Comment: Indeed, there is. Forgot about that since that was added to recent Framework version - downvoter, suggestion is STILL a VALID one.